# Javascript (Mobile) - Lazy Load Images with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) Jquery plugin for a mobile app I'm writing. The plugin works well enough except for the issue that it doesn't detect images that are in the view after the page loads. Here's the code I was previously using when I was designing in Chrome on my Mac, bit of a cheat but worked, though it doesn't work on an iPhone for example. How could I make this work? Any help is appreciated!

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
  placeholder: 'img/img_placeholder.jpg',
  threshold: 800,
  effect: "fadeIn"
});

$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: 2
}, '50');
```

Comment: I had a similar issue using this plugin; are you assigning the img some default size using CSS? That fixed the problem in my environment (although I do admit that was for desktop browsers) could be worth a try though.

Comment: Nah, unfortunately images are dynamically sized, I just have a max width set for my row's div.

Comment: Yep max-height/width didn't work, is it possible to set a fixed size and then change it with jquery css? My experience with it was that the fixed size forced the browser to realize "something goes here" for lack of a better word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can resolve your problem? [jqueryless lazy image load](https://github.com/ezYZ/Lazy-Load-Images-without-jQuery)

Comment: Gave it a shot, but unfortunately a no go. :( Same problem.

Comment: Just for idea. Not possible to use dynamical loading instead of lazy load?